# How to add directory to include path in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

This question should be is trivial enough but i didn't find answer. 
I have the following hierarchy:

- source.cpp
- thirdparty

  - Include

    - pelib

      - PeLib.h
    - test.cpp

I need to include `"pelib/PeLib.h"`.
If I add `$(ProjectDir)/thirdparty/Include` to include directories I can only `#include "test.cpp"` but can't `#include "pelib/PeLib.h"`.

Comment: Should work with `#include <pelib/PeLib.h>`

Comment: btw. .cpp files aren't meant to be included.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/) (thanks @umläute) your code should work. My guess is you variable `$(ProjectDir)` is not pointing the directory you think.

Try adding the full path to your `thirdparty/Include` to include directories and try again.

Comment: this is a bit misleading: `"incl.h"` is searched for in the relative path and then (as fallback) in the include-path. check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/)